# Зеркальное копирование данных из топика Apache-Kafka

Tags: linux, apache, apache-kafka

Как при помощи утилиты зеркального копирования kafka-mirror-maker.sh скопировать данные из топика source-кластера Kafka в топик target-кластера с другим именем?

К примеру: в первом кластере Kafka есть топик с именем test_topic_names, я хочу забрать данные из этого топика и скопировать содержимое в другой кластер Kafka в топик с другим именем test_topic.

Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Версии исходного кластера и целевого одинаковые?

Comment: Версия целевого кластера 2.0.0, версия исходного 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо написать свой `MessageHandler`, имплементирующий интерфейс `MirrorMakerMessageHandler`, и передать класс в аргументах к MirrorMaker (`--message.handler`). В `MessageHandler` будут подаваться на вход все сообщения из исходного в кластера, с которыми вы вольны делать все, что угодно. Подробнее можно прочитать тут: https://github.com/gwenshap/kafka-examples/blob/master/MirrorMakerHandler/README.md , https://www.opencore.com/blog/2017/1/170131-mirrormaker-change-topic/ , пример имплементации можно увидеть тут: https://github.com/opencore/mirrormaker_topic_rename .

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ!